# Write full log to file in python not just the message

Tags: logging, python-3.7

Given a simple code like this:

```
import logging
logging.root.handlers.append(logging.FileHandler("./log.log"))
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(name)s - '
                           '%(filename)s: %(funcName)s(): %(lineno)s: '
                           '%(message)s', datefmt='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S',
                    level=logging.INFO)
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def test():
    log.info("Test")

test()
```

with the goal to output the log both to stderr and the log.log file, stderr gets `03/12/2020 14:51:09 - INFO - __main__ - temp.py: test(): 15: Test` while the file just gets `Test`. Is there a way to get the full log line both in the file and in stderr? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it! Ok, so it is easier than I thought. I was looking at the wrong stuff. Here is my code and works like a charm! Pay attention to the `handlers` parameter.

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(name)s - '
                           '%(filename)s: %(funcName)s(): %(lineno)s: '
                           '%(message)s', datefmt='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S',
                    level=logging.INFO,
                    handlers=[logging.FileHandler("./log.log"),
                    logging.StreamHandler()])
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def test():
    log.info("Test")

test()
```

When I run this code, I get the line below in both the log file and the output stream.

```
03/13/2020 11:35:44 - INFO - __main__ - temp.py: test(): 26: Test
```

Nice!